# HDMI and USB-C ports dead on HP ZBook Studio

Tags: hdmi, usb-c, thunderbolt, hp-laptop

In my laptop (HP ZBook Studio G5) the HDMI stopped working and apparently USB-C ports also. I suspected initially that it could be because of the latest BIOS upgrade that Windows decided to do by themselves (but that's another story).

However, I rolled back from the latest 1.23 to the older 1.20 and the problem persists. External HDMI screen is not recognized, even though it looks like it's doing something. HP Ethernet dongle does not work either, and I can't charge my phone anymore using the USB-C port. This is NOT a driver problem or a Windows specific problem, as I have exactly the same behaviour on my Linux installation.

What makes me very confused though is that a USB-C docking station we have at my university seems to work OK and actually I even have external monitor with that.

What's going on here? Any ideas?

Comment: Get the HP Hardware Diagnostic App and run a full set of Hardware Tests.  Make sure motherboard and memory are both tested.

Comment: @John You mean the Windows version or the one that runs from the BIOS Setup utility?

Comment: You should be able to use the Windows version since the laptop is running.

Comment: A problem that stretches across multiple operating system installations suggest a hardware problem. I assume you have tried multiple Type-C USB cables to verify the problem with charging the phone isn't a cable problem?

Comment: @John Just ran the fast diagnostics test. System board OK, same with memory, video memory and Thunderbolt. Didn't run the full RAM check because it would take 3 hours - maybe I'll do it later :S

Comment: @Ramhound I agree with your remark, I'm just trying to pinpoint which part of the hardware is busted. I didn't try with different cables, but the same cable works on other PCs so... Also the laptop doesn't always charge from USB-C; I have to try a few times by plugging/unplugging, or rebooting... Which part can affect both functionalities (HDMI and USB-C) if it goes kaputt?

Comment: It sounds like a motherboard problem.

Comment: Another item point to controller hardware: " I can't charge my phone anymore using the USB-C port." If you no longer have DC (not signal) on the USB jack, that points to hardware.

Comment: How is it possible that the docking station works? I do have second monitor, keyboard, mouse, power... WTH? Also, which component (internally) is responsible for these? I looked up for motherboard schematics without any success...

Comment: @Ramhound Honest to god I didn't do anything, but it works again. Second display works fine over HDMI, USB-C devices are properly working. I'm afraid to start plugging in and out things as I have to do work now, but hey, it works! Maybe some bad soldering? I'm glad it's not a vital component (GPU, chipset, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all these months, I just managed not only to fix it but also find the actual cause.

A bit of history first: a few weeks after my initial question, I gave it one more try and both the USB-C and the HDMI ports were working fine. I was surprised to say the least (but also suspicious), that something that looked as a hardware problem managed to resolve by itself.

Until I got it again today. No HDMI or USB-C working. And I became VERY suspicious. What all these ports have in common? I can't know exactly, but they are on the same side of the motherboard, so I assumed they probably share the same power line. Then I also remembered: the previous day I used one of the docks at the university library, which was connected through one of the USB-C ports. If that dock is poorly designed/manufactured, it can mess with the USB subsystem and then trigger the overcurrent protection, which then in turn, shuts down completely the power line.

In order to "reset" the protection I had to follow the steps from [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Video-Display-and-Touch/All-USB-ports-not-working-How-to-reset-the-BIOS/td-p/8465930).

1. Disconnect all USB devices.
2. Unplug the power
3. Hold down the on switch for 10 seconds.
4. Plug back in and press the POWER button
5. If it does not turn on, then hold down the POWER button for 30 seconds.

Eventually, this had it fixed.